# Android RTSP Client

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, rtsp, rtsp-client

What are the possible RTSP clients that can Stream live RTSP videos from an IP Camera on Android? Please don't mention me the Android VideoView/MediaPlayer, they have an unbearable buffering delay which causes the whole stream to be delayed for 7-8 seconds. I tried to find a solution to reduce their buffering size but I couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success with the VLC implementation. You can find an example here https://github.com/pedroSG94/vlc-example-streamplayer

you add

```
implementation 'com.github.pedroSG94.vlc-example-streamplayer:pedrovlc:2.5.14v3'
```

... to your dependencies and then more or less go (in Kotlin):

```
val surfaceView: SurfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView)
vlcVideoLibrary = VlcVideoLibrary(this, this, surfaceView)
vlcVideoLibrary?.play(rtspUrlString);
```

... in your Activity

There's an example implementation in the project.

Answer (score 0):

you could have a look at this one

bsplayer -- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bsplayer.bspandroid.free

have used it occasionally and it has been pretty good (Sony Arc)

but its performance will depend on stuff outside your control

[RTSP Client in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380563/rtsp-client-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: YES!, I tried it, it only introduce 2 seconds delay! so it's good. But, I don't know how they do it! I mean i want to embed such client into my application, how can I?

Comment: Did you found a solution? I have similar problem... :)