# Broadcasting Video Over RTMP - Android

Tags: android, rtmp, android-broadcast

I Have to develop a App Which can broadcast live stream to the Wowza Server over RTMP Protocol in H.264 format. I am looking for a library of the RTMP protocol that can help me publish the stream to Server.

Ignore me if this Question is been already posted.

Thanks !

Comment: Again, the question is perfectly valid and should not have been closed.

Answer (score 6):

I also have a similar problem, and what I found.

First of all `RTMP` hasn't native support from Android.

1. [Aftek Android RTMP library](http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-RTMP-library.shtml). (not free)
2. [Smaxe RTMP Library](http://www.smaxe.com/juvclient.jsf).(not free)
3. [Android RTMP Client](https://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/). (free)

If you will find another solution, please, provide it.

 I hope follow links helps you.

**Update** (answer for your e-mail)

About RTSP:

1. Very useful opensource sample [Spydroid Ipcamera](https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/)
2. Also check [SO question about RTSP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380563/rtsp-client-in-android?rq=1)

And try to find another SO question. This subject frequently discussed.

Comment: I updated my answer (answer for your e-mail). Check it please.

Comment: @jimpanzer...did you have any sample using third option. How good is the stream with this option?

Comment: @Saty, unfortunately I don't finish my research on this subject and I can't give you any information about that. I hope that for 2.5 years something changed on RTMP usage on android.

Answer (score 2):

**You can do with Adobe AIR Platform for Android/iOS Devices.**

I am not sure that you can do this with Android SDK, So if you are looking to seriously do that.Go for Adobe AIR.

Comment: This is not much possible as there is an issue with adobe AIR when comes in the case of Linux servers as they have no support in Linux. The next case is that, this may not be apt for Google Nexus also. I too is now in such a situation.

Answer (score 1):

While this question is old, if some one is still looking for library for android to rtmp to Wowza , they can checkout Intel INDE, which has built in support for WOWZA

> > https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials

Comment: There are many on the list. Which one is valid for streaming video to / from Wowza?